# pgfplots: How to get coordinates, draws as a style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

I draw these two points

```
\fill[cyan] (yticklabel cs:0.5) coordinate[](X2) circle(2pt); 
\fill[red] (yticklabel* cs:0.5) coordinate[](X1) circle(2pt);
```

So my question is: How could I have that as a style, so that I can say e.g. 
`\begin{axis}[drawpoints, ....]`  
There must be something with `path picture` or `insert path` or...

It may be a curious question, but I need that for some measurement methods, and I want to be flexible where I use that method.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\begin{axis}[
clip=false, 
ylabel=yLabel,
every y tick label/.append style={draw}, 
every axis y label/.append style={draw}, 
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-500) (1,1) (2,2)};

\fill[cyan] (yticklabel cs:0.5) coordinate[](X2) circle(2pt); 
\fill[red] (yticklabel* cs:0.5) coordinate[](X1) circle(2pt); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgfplots` has some hooks that lets you insert code at various points, see section 4.25 *Miscellaneous options* in the `pgfplots` manual.

Not entirely sure which is the best one, but `before end axis` seems to do the job:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  drawpoints/.style={
    before end axis/.code={
      \fill[cyan] (yticklabel cs:0.5) coordinate (X2) circle(2pt); 
      \fill[red] (yticklabel* cs:0.5) coordinate (X1) circle(2pt); 
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
drawpoints,
clip=false, 
ylabel=yLabel,
every y tick label/.append style={draw}, 
every axis y label/.append style={draw}, 
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-500) (1,1) (2,2)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, very nice. ;)